# Resolve promise in sequence with object instance method chain

Tags: javascript, promise

Let's say you have

```
// this is a util function used for the following
const task = (name, waitTimeInMs) => new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(() => { 
     resolve(name); 
  }, waitTimeInMs);
})



function Person () {
  this.promise = Promise.resolve();
}

Person.prototype.walk = function() {
  // `task` is returning a promise
  task('walk', 100);

  return this;
}

Person.prototype.eat = function() {
  // `task` is returning a promise
  task('eat', 500);

  return this;
}


const person = new Person();
```

What should I do in the prototype method `eat` and `talk`, so that I can have

```
person.walk().talk().walk().talk().walk();
```

to return the exact same sequence

```
// walk
// talk
// walk
// talk
// walk
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "return" the sequence, exactly? The method calls all return `this` so how is the client supposed to access the result? Usually, there is some sort of final function in the chain like `.end()` that gives you an array of the promises, or something like that. This may well not be the best design for whatever problem you're trying to solve so a bit more context is welcome to help you avoid the [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676).

Comment: `task(...).then(msg => console.log(msg))`?

Comment: You already have `this.promise`. That means you probably planned to use it somehow. Can you explain your intention, what you had in mind when you wrote `Promise.resolve()`?

Comment: Btw, don't name your classes in plural. Your instance probably doesn't represent a people, but a single person - so the class should be named `Person`.

Comment: @ggorlen this is what I would like to do

By calling `person.walk().talk().walk().talk().walk();`

It will output `walk talk walk talk walk`.  But please note that `task` is a promise.

Comment: Thanks, but that's still unclear. First of all, what programming feature does this actually implement? Secondly, why do you need promises for it? All you have to do is `console.log` in each call synchronously -- or are you hoping to wait for some promise associated with each call to finish before logging? If so, `await` a promise in the class variable (the previous call's promise), then reassign it to the next promise in the chain. But this seems strange -- you'd usually return promises and let the caller `await`. More information seems necessary to motivate whatever it is you're trying to do.

Comment: @R.R Why did you remove the `this.promise = Promise.resolve();` from your question? It was the right approach. Try to go through with this idea! Where are you stuck?

Comment: @ggorlen It seems pretty clear to me that `task` is some asynchronous task, exemplified by the timeout, that should be run from the method calls, in sequence.

Comment: @Bergi that's fine, but OP hasn't really motivated anything about why they want to do any of this, so my point is that it's trivially solvable. They should provide details as to what they're really trying to accomplish so there's good reason for doing whatever they're asking about and we can avoid random guesswork answers like the ones currently posted. Usually, promises don't "just" `console.log`, usually the result matters programmatically.

Comment: Thanks for the edit that brought `this.promise = Promise.resolve();` back, and I'm happy to provide an answer that builds on that, but could you still also add an explanation of what you had planned to use it for?

Comment: It was an interview question I came across a while ago and it is more for academic curiosity.   @Bergi

Comment: It looks like they want you to build a queue: `this.promise = this.promise.then(() => task('walk', 100));`. Bonus points for proper error handling.

Answer (score -4):

You could try pushing the task promises onto an array stored within the instance of person and then access the results of all tasks, in order, with Promise.all

```js
const task = (name, waitTimeInMs) => new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(() => { 
     resolve(name); 
  }, waitTimeInMs);
})


function Person () {
  this.promise = Promise.resolve();
  this.tasks = [];
}

Person.prototype.walk = function() {
  this.tasks.push(task('walk', 100));
  return this;
}

Person.prototype.talk = function() {
  this.tasks.push(task('talk', 500));
  return this;
}

const person = new Person();

const { tasks } = person.walk().talk().walk().talk().walk();
Promise.all(tasks).then(results => console.log(results));
```

Answer (score -5):

This sort of works, but that's exactly the kind of atrocious code I would personally never use.
I actually hope to see a better solution emerge.
This "modern" JavaScript is supposed to be simpler, easier to use and more intuitive, but so far it only managed to melt my brains out of my ears.

Anyway, the idea is to delay the execution of the promise-wrapped tasks until someone actually awaits the `People` object.
Once `People` is made "thenable", it can get activated by the JS runtime whenever a `promise.then()` would, including in an `await` statement within an `async` function.

I stuck to ES 5 style for the class declaration to match your example, but switching to ES6 syntax should not make much difference.

```
function People (name) {
    this.name = name; // just to make use of the actual class
    this.calls = [];  // store task parameters
}

People.prototype = {

    walk : function () { return this.prepare ("walk", 900)},
    talk : function () { return this.prepare ("talk", 100)},
    eat  : function () { return this.prepare ("eat" , 500)},
    
    // the chained calls simply prepare a list of parameters
    prepare: function (action, delay) {
        this.calls.push({a:action, d:delay});
        return this;
    },
    
    // the "then" special method triggers actual execution
    then : function () {
        if (this.calls.length != 0) {
            this.task(this.calls.shift());
        }
    },
    
    // I assume "task" is meant to be a method of "People",
    // or else what is the point of defining a class?
    
    task : function ({a:action, d:delay}) {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            console.log(this.name + " starts " + action + "ing");
            setTimeout(() => {
                console.log(this.name + " is done " + action + "ing");
                resolve (this);
            }, delay);
        });
    }
};
```

So you can use this horrible hack either the `async/await` way:

```
 var Bob = new People("Bob");
 (async () => 
    await Bob.walk().talk().eat()
 )()
```

...Or like a pseudo-promise.

```
 Bob.walk().talk().eat().then()
```

In both cases you should see something like this in your console:

```
Bob starts walking
Bob is done walking
Bob starts talking
Bob is done talking
Bob starts eating
Bob is done eating
```

The `then` takes no parameter for now, but you can return a true promise instead of the current promise-wrapped `undefined` result if your tasks actually produce some data and/or have errors to report. That should allow to continue chaining any number of `.then()` calls.

Just make sure not to return `this` from within the `then` method or you'll go into an infinite loop and basically brick your browser.